# Save an image placed on a webform. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I want to save an image that is placed on my webform by clicking on a button. And the image has to be saved in different formats such as .jpg, .bmp. Please help!

Comment: can you a bit precise in your request?

Comment: The image is placed in update panel. Image gets saved when a click on a button 'save'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Image.save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx):

```
public void Save(string filename, ImageFormat format)
```

Comment: What Code?? You write the saving routine on the ButtonClick event, and replace filename and fileformat with the information you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this,

[.Net Image Uploading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1956/NET-Image-Uploading)